# Aside from switching to a Bayesian approach, how can I quantify the strength of evidence for a null result of a linear mixed effects model?

Tags: regression, hypothesis-testing, mixed-model

I've run a linear mixed effects model with a null result that would be quite interesting for the field. Is there a test I can run that would bolster the claim that the two groups are indeed equivalent? I know that Bayesian analyses are ideal for this, but I am hesitant because of a lack of previous literature that could provide a prior.

Would simply running a post-hoc power analysis be enough?

Comment: A post hoc power analysis is just a transformation of the $p$-value$---$it doesn't tell you anything. However, you might be interested in two one sides tests of equivalence (TOST).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I've come across TOST, however, I'm not sure if it's possible to implement that given that I'm running a mixed effects model. Have you ever come across someone doing that?